# Как использовать двойные кавычки в xml?

Tags: c++, qt, xml

Использую *QT'ишный* QDomDocument, возникает проблема при использовании [QDomDocument::setContent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#setContent), он ругается на эту строку `< field regexp = "text".+"text" >`

Я пробовал так:

- `< field regexp = "text"".+""text" >`
- `< field regexp = "text'"'.+'"'text" >`
- `< field regexp = "text\".+\"text" >`

Comment: Атрибуты xml можно заключать как в двойные, так и в одинарные кавычки: `'text".+"text'`. Соответственно, внутри можно использовать кавычки другого типа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `&quot;` для экранирования кавычек:

```xml
<field regexp="text&quot;.+&quot;text">
```